# PgAdmin 4.14 connection error in cloudSQL : could not send data to server, socket is not connected, could not send ssl negotiation packet

Tags: pgadmin-4, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect cloud sql with pgadmin but it throws error when I try to execute query.

> "Could not send Data to server, socket is not connected, could not
>   sent SSL negotiation pocket"

But When I connect with different Database tool like DBViz / Psql, I can execute the query - no such error in other tools.
I am kind of lost in the error, could you please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 4):

Switching from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** allowed the connection successfully.